# Remove String from Sequence in one Dataframe based on another Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below

**stringTokenDF**

```scala
+-------+------------------
|Id     | Tokens
+-------+------------------
|1      |[A, B, C, D]
|1      |[B, C, D, G]                                                 
|1      |[A, D, E]                                                     
|1      |[B, C, F]                                                
|2      |[A, C, D]
|2      |[C, E, F]
|2      |[A, C, D, H]
+-------+------------------
```

Another dataframe as shown below

**leastFrequenctDf**

```scala
+-------+------------------
|Id     | LeastFrequentWords
+-------+------------------
|1      |[E, G]
|2      |[E, F, H]
```

Now i want to remove the string from Sequence in Tokens  column of stringTokenDF which are in LeastFrequenctWords Sequence belonging to same id. My output should looks like below.

```scala
+-------+------------------
|Id     | Tokens
+-------+------------------
|1      |[A, B, C, D]
|1      |[B, C, D]                                                 
|1      |[A, D ]                                                     
|1      |[B, C, F]                                                
|2      |[A, C, D]
|2      |[C ]
|2      |[A, C, D]
+-------+------------------
```

I tried using join and intersect of Sequence but it is not giving me correct result as above.

```scala
val  intersectorUDF = udf((seq1: Seq[String], seq2: Seq[String]) => {
    seq1.intersect(seq2)
} )

stringTokenDF.join(leastFrequenctDf, stringTokenDF("id") === leastFrequenctDf("id")).
withColumn("intersectedToken",intersectorUDF(stringTokenDF("Tokens"),
leastFrequenctDf("LeastFrequentWords"))
```

what would be the correct way to achieve this in spark scala?

Comment: in `leastFrequenctDf` is id always unique?

Comment: yes. It will be unique always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two DataFrames and apply a `UDF` that computes the `diff` between the two sequence columns:

```scala
val stringTokenDF = Seq(
  (1, Seq("A", "B", "C", "D")),
  (1, Seq("B", "C", "D", "G")),
  (1, Seq("A", "D", "E")),
  (1, Seq("B", "C", "F")),
  (2, Seq("A", "C", "D")),
  (2, Seq("C", "E", "F")),
  (2, Seq("A", "C", "D", "H"))
).toDF("Id", "Tokens")

val leastFrequenctDf = Seq(
  (1, Seq("E", "G")),
  (2, Seq("E", "F", "H"))
).toDF("Id", "LeastFrequentWords")

def diff = udf( (s1: Seq[String], s2: Seq[String]) =>
  s1 diff s2
)

stringTokenDF.join(leastFrequenctDf, Seq("Id")).
  select($"Id", diff($"Tokens", $"LeastFrequentWords").as("Tokens")).
  show

// +---+------------+
// | Id|      Tokens|
// +---+------------+
// |  1|[A, B, C, D]|
// |  1|   [B, C, D]|
// |  1|      [A, D]|
// |  1|   [B, C, F]|
// |  2|   [A, C, D]|
// |  2|         [C]|
// |  2|   [A, C, D]|
// +---+------------+
```